# Como se realiza un Header dinamico - Ag Grid (Angular)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, aggrid

**Directo al grano**

Tengo una grid y quiero que las columnas vayan aumentando conforme tenga en los datos.
Me explico.
tengo estos datos

```js
this.rowData = [
        {
            fecha: '03/march/1994',
            estatus: 'Activo',
            fee: 'BANCO',
            banks: {
                empresa1: 'Abc',
                empresa2: 'Abccc',
                empresa3: 'sss'
                /* esta cantidad puede cambiar */
            }
        }
    ];
```

el array "banks" se puede incrementar o volverse mas pequeño, depende de lo que una api que estoy consumiendo me devuelva.

**Estos son los campos de Ag-Grid**

```js
 private createGrid(): void { 
    this.grid = assignNewObjet(GRID);
    this.grid.columnDefs = [
        {
            headerName: 'Fecha',
            field: 'fecha',
            maxWidth: 220,
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Estatus',
            field: 'estatus',
            maxWidth: 220,
        },
        {
            headerName: 'Tipo de recuado',
            field: 'fee',
        }
    ];

    this.pinnedBottomRowData = [
        {
            status: 'Total:',
            fee: '$ 200000',
        },
      ];
}
```

```html
<ag-grid-angular
                    class="ag-theme-material w-100-p highGridThree"
                    [gridOptions]="grid"
                    [pinnedBottomRowData]="pinnedBottomRowData"
                    [rowData]="rowData"
                    [pagination]="true"
                >
                </ag-grid-angular>
```

y lo que quiero es que en el Grid, se agregue dinamicamente los nombres de las keys de banks
y que se muestre algo como esto

[image: Ag-Grid]

Comment: Podrias mostrar el codigo de assignNewObjet(GRID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creación dinámica de columnas  AG desde JSON
Configurando las definiciones de columna desde un JSON en **forma dinamica**
Hay que obtener las claves de los datos Json utilizar getColumnDefs()..setColumnDefs(colDefs)...setRowData(data)
Ejemplo con modo comun y modo dinamico para objetos mas complejos no hay que modificar mucho  este codigo guia en el link
[teoria](https://blog.ag-grid.com/dynamically-setting-ag-grid-columns-from-json/)

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AgGridAngular } from 'ag-grid-angular';

interface Data {
  make:string,
  model:string,
  price:number
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-grid',
  templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid.component.css']
})

export class GridComponent implements OnInit,AfterViewInit {
/*
  @ViewChild('agGrid') agGrid!: AgGridAngular;
  */
  @ViewChild('gGridEmpty') gGridEmpty!: AgGridAngular;
  

  columnDefs0 = [
  ];
  gridOptions = {

    defaultColDef: {
        sortable: true,
        filter: 'agTextColumnFilter',
        resizable: true
    },

    columnDefs: this.columnDefs0,
  
    pagination: true
};
/*
  columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make',filter: true, checkboxSelection: true},
    {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model',sortable: true, filter: true},
    {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price',sortable: true, filter: true},
    { field: 'athlete', headerName: 'Best Athlete' } ,
    { field: 'athlete', headerValueGetter: (params:any) => 'New Athlete' }
];
*/
rowData!: Observable<Data[]>;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient ) { 
    this.rowData = this.http.get<Data[]>('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/small-row-data.json');
  }

  ngOnInit(): void { }
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.rowData.subscribe(data=>{
      console.log('data[0]',data[0])
    
      const colDefs= this.gGridEmpty.api.getColumnDefs() ;
      console.log('colDefs:Definiciones de columna',colDefs)
       colDefs!.length=0;
       // Get all the keys from the first Object in the JSON.
          const keys = Object.keys(data[0])
          console.log('Obtenemos las claves keys',keys)
          // agregamos cada key a colDefs con el valor de field
        
          keys.forEach(key => colDefs!.push({field : key}));
          // establecemos las nuevas definiciones utilizando el array modificado
          this.gGridEmpty.api.setColumnDefs(colDefs!);
            // el name del field lo mapeamos al rowData
          this.gGridEmpty.api.setRowData(data)
  }
    )
  }
  

 /*
  getSelectedRows(): void {
      const selectedNodes = this.agGrid.api.getSelectedNodes();
      console.log('selectedNodes',selectedNodes)
        const selectedData = selectedNodes.map(node => node.data);
        console.log('selectedData',selectedData)
     const selectedDataStringPresentation = selectedData.map(node => `${node.make} ${node.model}`).join(', ');
  
       console.log(  `Selected nodes: ${selectedDataStringPresentation}`);
     }
     */
}
```

```html
<!--
<button (click)="getSelectedRows()">Get Selected Rows</button>
<ag-grid-angular 
    #agGrid
    style="width: 700px; height: 500px;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
    [rowData]="rowData | async" 
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    rowSelection="multiple"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>

<br>
-->
<ag-grid-angular 
    #gGridEmpty
    style="width: 700px; height: 500px;" 
    class="ag-theme-balham"
   
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    >
</ag-grid-angular>
```

> Tambien ag grid  permite agrupar
> en children

[Column Groups](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/column-groups/)
Para agregar las empresas como headers en un modelo comun

```js
this.columnDefs = [
  
  { 
      headerName: 'Fecha',
      field: 'fecha',
      maxWidth: 220,
  },
  {
      headerName: 'Estatus',
      field: 'estatus',
      maxWidth: 220,
  },
  {
      headerName: 'Tipo de recuado',
      field: 'fee',
  },
  { 
        headerName: 'Empresa1',
       field: 'banks.empresa1
  },
  
  {     headerName: 'Empresa2',
       field: 'banks.empresa2'
  },
  { 
         headerName: 'Empresa3',
       field: 'banks.empresa3'
  }
]
```

En repositorio github en la ruta grid codigo en forma dinamica y tambien confeccionar una tabla con la respuesta de jsonplaceholder-->users
[ruta grid](https://github.com/nestdanchia/NgZone/tree/main/src/app/grid)